# Check for file with same filename, but different extension

Tags: php, file, image-processing, file-upload

I have a directory contain jpeg and raw image files. Some jpeg files have a raw file version of them, some don't. Luckily, if a jpeg has a raw file they are named the same (excluding the extension). So, I need a way to check this directory for a matching raw file of the same filename, exclusing file extesion. the raw file, file extension could be pretty much anything.

Any ideas how I can do this? I have the filename (excluding extesion) stored of $filename at the moment.

To explain further. I have a directory with the following files in it:

```
cat.jpg
dog.jpg
bird.jpg
cat.raf
dog.foo
```

I need to match cat.jpg to cat.rag and dog.jpg to dog.foo. These have just been extracted from a uploaded zip file.

Comment: post some pseudocode as i don't understand what you want to do after

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try searching for files starting with the same name:

```
$fileWithoutExtension = basename($filename, '.jpg');
$allFilesWithThisName = glob($fileWithoutExtension . '.*');
if (count($allFilesWithThisName)) {
    echo 'There is another file with this name';
}
```

Comment: As the .jpg file already exists, count must be greater one: `if (1 < count($allFilesWithThisName)) {`

Comment: not sure if this actually works as it doesn't seem to check a particular directory.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have the filename w/o the extension, you can just check if the raw file exists ([`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)):

```
   if (file_exists($filename.'.raw')) {
     echo 'RAW file exists:', $filename , "\n";
   }
```

But this seems so trivial to me, that I might did not understood your question completely.

Comment: yeah, the problem is the raw files don't have a certain file extension. I just know that they won't be jpeg

Comment: Okay, then [Sjoerd's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356684/check-for-file-with-same-filename-but-different-extension/6356729#6356729) has the solution, albeit it needs a slight edit. Added a comment there.